# How to get symbolic partial derivative with respect to time

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, derivative

Let's say I have this function

```
f(t) = 4*sin(a(t)) + x(t)*y(t) + h + cos(y(t))*sin(x(t))
```

How would I compute its derivative with respect to time?

Comment: I have no idea why this post has been put on hold. I'm aware of `diff` for symbolic derivative but not the problem I've stated. The problem is that some variables are depending on time so it is not straightforward to how to solve it. I've read Matlab's documentation but there is no an example provided regarding this matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare the variables and the functions inside it as being symbolic and then use diff:

```
clear
clc

syms a x y t h

a(t) = symfun(sym('a(t)'), t)
x(t) = symfun(sym('x(t)'), t)
y(t) = symfun(sym('y(t)'), t)

F = 4*sin(a(t)) + x(t)*y(t) + h + cos(y(t))*sin(x(t))

DerF_t = diff(F,t)
```

Giving the following (messy) output:

```
F =   h + 4*sin(a(t)) + cos(y(t))*sin(x(t)) + x(t)*y(t)
DerF_t =   x(t)*diff(y(t), t) + y(t)*diff(x(t), t) + 4*cos(a(t))*diff(a(t), t) + cos(x(t))*cos(y(t))*diff(x(t), t) - sin(x(t))*sin(y(t))*diff(y(t), t)
```

Note that since a(t),x(t) and y(t) are simply defined as functions of 't' we are stuck with their 'symbolic' derivative (I don't know the term for that sorry)...i.e. diff(a(t)) for instance.

Hope it's what you were after!

Comment: Which Matlab's version you use? I'm getting this error `??? Undefined function or method 'symfun' for input arguments of type 'sym'.`

Comment: Mhh I use R2013a. Can you use something like syms a x y t h;
a(t) = sym('a(t)') for example?

Comment: I don't have access to the symbolic toolbox right now; I'll try different alternatives when I get home. I'll update my answer then.

Comment: thank you so much. I got it to work. I used the newest version of Matlab in my university and I got the answer. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Oh and BTW I don't understand why your question was put on hold I think it was perfectly fine.

Comment: No idea man. They didn't even bother to mention the reason.